# Understand fmt formatter parse function

Tags: c++, fmt

I'm trying to under the parse function for creating a formatter for a custom type in fmt. In their documentation (https://fmt.dev/dev/api.html) there is this line that has some sort of loop construct I haven't seen before:

```
auto it = ctx.begin(), end = ctx.end();
if (it != end && (*it == 'f' || *it == 'e')) presentation = *it++;
```

It's obviously a loop using iterators, presumably something new in C++17.  What is it?  Full example here: https://godbolt.org/z/fEGvaj

Comment: ? It's an `if`. There is no loop...

Comment: The comments in the code you linked explain what the code does. What part of that didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `formatter::parse` function takes a parse context `ctx` and checks if the range `[ctx.begin(), ctx.end())` contains format specifiers `f` or `e` in this example.

```
if (it != end && (*it == 'f' || *it == 'e')) presentation = *it++;
    ^                 ^             ^
 check if the         check if the first
 range is empty       character is 'f' or 'e'
```

There is nothing particularly novel here, this code is compatible with C++98.

Comment: I think I got it...the loop is external to the parse function (i.e. parse is called repeatedly until the closing brace or end of string)....holy cow... I was way over thinking it... must've been a long day or something...thanks.  btw...the fmt library is awesome!

Comment: is `ctx.end()` pointing to the past end of the formatting string or just the last char of the string? From the example in api doc, it says the range `[begin, end)` is the rest of the formatting string. Then for a valid string how can it happen that `it == end`. Even if you provide `{}`, the range should contain a signel char `}`, which is not empty. But if I remove the `it != end` check, it crashes, making me thing that when `{}` is used as format string, the range does not contain the `}`.